# Should mysql transaction isolation level set to "read commited"?

Tags: mysql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

After my airflow upgraded to 2.0.0(and then 2.0.1) and scheduler expanded to 3 nodes, something weird happened：

- dagruns were success but the task instances were not scheduled at all
- task failed with a null hostname(https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13692)
- Task is set "upstream_failed" while upstream tasks are success(https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13671)

These phenomena never happened when there was only one scheduler node.

And I found that after task instances of a new dagrun were created by a scheduler node, they were not found in another scheduler node's task_instance_scheduling_decisions function.

Then I checked the mysql configurations and found transaction isolation was set to be Repeatable read by default.

After I set transaction isolation to be read commited, everything seems to be good now. But I still wonder are there any side effects?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, READ COMMITTED is different than REPEATABLE READ.

If you use REPEATABLE READ, then in this transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT * FROM mytable;

SELECT * FROM mytable; -- i.e. the same query

COMMIT;
```

You are guaranteed that both SELECTs return the same result (as long as they are not locking queries).

But in READ COMMITTED, if some other session has committed a change to data in between the two SELECTs, they can return different results.

In other words, REPEATABLE READ means your SELECT queries always return data that was committed at the moment your START TRANSACTION started. Whereas READ COMMITTED means your SELECT queries return data that was committed after your transaction started, up until the time each respective SELECT starts.

Both levels of transaction isolation have proper uses. But they do behave differently.